# In AIR, how do you create a windowed application that's not resizable?

Tags: air

How do I make my AIR app window not resizable? Note, I am not talking about any newly created window, but the actual AIR app's window (WindowedApplication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application.xml file, set resizable to false under initialWindow:

```
<application....>
    <!-- Normal app stuff like id, name, etc -->
    <initialWindow>
        <!-- Normal initialWindow stuff like content, title, systemChrome -->
        <minimizable>true</minimizable>
        <maximizable>false</maximizable>
        <resizable>false</resizable>
        <width>800</width>
        <height>600</height>
    </initialWindow>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var windowOptions:NativeWindowInitOptions = new NativeWindowInitOptions();
NativeWindowInitOptions.resizable = false;
```

See [here](http://www.webreference.com/programming/adobe_air/working_with_windows/2.html) for more info on what you can do with the window options.

Comment: widowOptions seems to only work for newly created NativeWindow.  In my case, I am looking to make my app's window (i.e. WindowedApplication.nativeWindow) not resizable, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

set the application's minwidth same as maxwidth and minheight same as maxheight

Comment: this is the long way, the correct way is posted by John Feminella